# Procedure for wrapping a superconducting coil around a cylindrical shell?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity, experimental-technique

I don't know if experimental physics questions are allowed on this site - please direct me to the proper SE if it doesn't belong here.

---

I need to wrap a few layers of superconducting wire (~80 micron diameter) around a cylindrical shell.  The shell is relatively small - about 20 cm long and 5 cm diameter; we're looking at about 3000 turns.

I've done some research and found some researchers had luck with a foot-controlled potter's wheel and Stycast 1265A/B as an adhesive on and between layers.  Curing time is about 24 hours and the configuration should hold well below 4 K.  However, it appears to be tricky to keep tension on the wire during the process and can lead to a very unpleasant mess (and a lot of wasted wire) if something goes wrong.

Does anyone have any tips on how to wrap a superconducting coil like this?

Comment: How about getting a winding machine? They aren't specified for superconducting wire, but you could adjust them. Don't know if it will work well in your case, as the wire properties and the adhesive properties need to be finetuned.

Comment: @Kurtovic, we've looked into armature winders, but like you suggest we don't need to do this *fast*, just safely.  We're not against buying more hardware, but I was hoping to find someone who has experience with this that can link to some resource that fully describes the procedure.